# Main data model on android

Tags: android

I have an android application with a number of activities.
I have a singleton class holding my main data model which all activities access to get data.

The problem is that sometimes the android GC decides to destroy my singleton when the app in the background (when you press the home button).
Is there anyway that I can bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this exact problem in a current application of mine, which needs to retain a large amount of data in various 'singleton' classes. The problem I encountered was as in your case; i.e. sometimes when bringing the application back to the foreground, some of the static 'singleton' classes have been destroyed.

The problem, I believe, is that the 'lifetime' of such classes can never be well defined or predicted. After all, it's a class sat there holding a reference to itself, so it's susceptible to being garbage collected when the system wants to grab some resources.

You're probably already aware that extending `android.app.Application` is a well-known alternative to using conventional Singletons. The solution that worked for me is to hold the actual instances of data singleton classes within an extension class of `android.app.Application`, whose lifecycle is well defined. Any other class that wants to access those singletons can obtain them using a getter in the `Application` class.

So for example I have a class called `AppState` that extends `Application`, that holds the instances within:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class AppState extends Application {
    ...

    // "Singleton" instances that this Application extension looks after
    private MSData   singletonInstanceMSData;


    public AppState() {
        ...
        singletonInstanceMSData = new MSData();
        ...


    // ---------------- Singleton instance control ----------------

    public MSData getMSData(){
        return singletonInstanceMSData;
    }


    // I also provide the means to 'reset' the instances on startup (this is
    // something I need to do for my application - you may or may not need to)
    public void resetControllerSpecificData(){
        singletonInstanceMSData.reset();
        ...
```

Don't forget you'll need to modify your manifest if you extend `Application`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read this solution before, and there was an argument whether this solution is right or wrong. If you say this one works for ya I'll give it a try, even though I cant really understand whats the difference: I mean, if my application goes to background and the OS decides to kill it, how will it "know" how to restore 'AppState' class last state?

Comment: If the system kills the entire process when the app is in the background, then the application will run from the beginning when you next start it. Then, it will construct the singleton structures just as it normally would at startup, and all is okay. The actual problem situation is when the application has not been killed and it is therefore resumed when you next start it, *but* the singleton classes have GC'd, meaning the app is resumed in a broken state; ie it's resuming but a singleton it created at startup is now missing. Using `Application` works because it always stays around.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, lifespan os singleton is lifespan of his classloader - also complete VM . When user  hit home button, your application goes in backgorund and is probably destroyed - you can not do anything against it.   Your best bet is to save whatever is necessary in your onPause() callback ( or just use write through in every change of datza if you really paranoid )

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also thought about this kind of solution, and I still have problem with it: I also have a Service - Sticky service - that the OS may also kill, and than it will be restarted (Sticky service...). Now, services doesnt have 'onPause()', so it cant save the state this way... If you have problem to the second solution, it would be great!